# Custom reports with Partner related fields in filters can't be run by portal user

Tags: custom-report-type, partner-portal, partner

When preparing reports for a portal user I find they are unable to run my custom "Account, Opportunity, and Partner" reports that reference a Partner field.  When they try to open such a report they get an error saying, "Invalid Report 
You cannot run this report because its formulas or filters are invalid or it references fields that are inaccessible to you. Please contact your administrator to update the report."
I've assigned the partner fields to be accessible to the portal user and I've assigned those fields to the partner in the custom report setup.  Is there a permission setting for Partner as a whole for portal users that I'm missing or some other suggestion as to what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

SalesForce Support stated portal users do not have access to "Partner" fields on reports.  Consequently, any report using partner fields as filters results in this message. SalesForce Support says this is intended functionality and will not be fixing this shortcoming in portal users and partner fields.